# sklearn.datasets and windows

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed scikit-learn on my win 8 PC (python 2.7 64bit). Now, when I try to import the data sets, it does not work because it cannot find the library

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

Should I install even other libraries or what should I do?

This is th errot I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
ImportError: No module named sklearn.datasets
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error that comes back? I can't tell you where to begin based on this, other than saying install a c compiler, setuptools, pip, and then re-install sklearn.

Comment: can you `import sklearn`?

Comment: You probably have several versions of Python installed on your system and you installed scikit-learn on a different Python that the one you are using. How did you install Python and scikit-learn?

Comment: @alexmulo then it seems it's your delusion that sklearn is installed on your sistem. How did you install it?

Comment: I thinke the problem is that I have two different python versions installed. I'll try uninstall all and to install only a python version

Comment: Maybe give anaconda a shot.